# Проблема с тестом в регулярных выражениях

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Задача: Реализовать удаление избыточных значений при вводе номера телефона в консоли и проверить соответствие номера формату мобильных номеров в России. Если введенную строку нельзя преобразовать в формат мобильного номера, отобразить сообщение о недопустимом вводе. Телефон можно вводить не только в формате 79091234567, но и с дополнительными символами.  [Примеры вводимых значений и результаты вывода программы](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bVF6.png)

*В результате, при вводе номера телефона в консоль, в предоставленном коде удалось реализовать условия удаления избыточных значений по всем предложенным вариантам, за исключением: 9-453-1234567.*

[Пройденные и ошибочные тесты](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3TAZ.png)

*Не могу понять в каком месте и каким образом прописать условие для корректной отработки теста. Ошибка, из-за которой тест не проходит, это номер начинающийся с 9 и имеющий 11 цифр. Согласно условию задания, при подобном вводе должно выводиться "Неверный формат номера". В моем случае происходит преобразование номера.

Пример 9-453-1234567 (**Должно выводится "Неверный формат номера"**), а выводится **"74531234567"**

Код:

```
package practice.regex; 
 
import java.util.Scanner; 
 
public class PhoneCleanerRegex { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        while (true) { 
            String input = scanner.nextLine(); 
            if (input.equals("0")) { 
                scanner.close(); 
                break; 
            } 
            // TODO:напишите ваш код тут, результат вывести в консоль. 
            String regex = "[^0-9]"; 
            String phoneNumber = input.replaceAll(regex, ""); 
            if (phoneNumber.length() > 11 || phoneNumber.length() < 10) { 
                System.out.println("Неверный формат номера"); 
                break; 
            } else { 
                if ((phoneNumber.charAt(0) == '8') || (phoneNumber.length() != 10)) { 
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst("[0-9]{1}", "7"); 
                    System.out.println(phoneNumber); 
                    break; 
                } 
                if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) { 
                    System.out.println("7" + phoneNumber); 
                } else { 
                    System.out.println(phoneNumber); 
                } 
                break; 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: У тебя выполняется это условие

`if ((phoneNumber.charAt(0) == '8') || (phoneNumber.length() != 10)) { 
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst("[0-9]{1}", "7"); 
                    System.out.println(phoneNumber); 
                    break; 
                } `

Comment: Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё решила. Использовала метод charAt(0) == '9', переставила все if с номером 10 на начало и добавила необходимый if в конец программы.

```
package practice.regex;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PhoneCleanerRegex {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            String input = scanner.nextLine();
            if (input.equals("0")) {
                scanner.close();
                break;
            }
            // TODO:напишите ваш код тут, результат вывести в консоль.
            String regex = "[^0-9]";
            String phoneNumber = input.replaceAll(regex, "");
            if (phoneNumber.length() > 11 || phoneNumber.length() < 10) {
                System.out.println("Неверный формат номера");
                break;
            }
            if (phoneNumber.length() == 10) {
                System.out.println("7" + phoneNumber);
            }
            else {
                if (phoneNumber.charAt(0) == '8') {
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replaceFirst("[0-9]", "7");
                    System.out.println(phoneNumber);
                    break;
                }
                if (phoneNumber.charAt(0) == '9') {
                    System.out.println("Неверный формат номера");
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println(phoneNumber);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А если будет начинаться с 5? добавится ещё одно условие получается, и так можно долго.
Лучше напишите реджекс, который будет анализировать номер телефона на корректность и всё